# Array.slice using index number contained in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.I'm trying to remove some elements from [arr] at index numbers in [removeIndex].

```
var removeIndex = [2,3];
var arr = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1];
for (let i = 0; i < removeIndex.length;i++){
arr.splice(removeIndex[i],1);
}
console.log(arr)

// output Array(5) [ 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ]
//expected [ 1,1,1,1,1]
```

Both the 0's are at arr[2] and arr[3] position and should get removed,however the above code doesnt work.I suspect it has to do with the loop re-arranging the index numbers.Any alternate solution?

Comment: After you've removed the zero at index 2, the zero formerly at index 3 is now the zero at index 2. Have you considered using `.filter` instead? Alternatively, start with the *last* index, not the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely suspect correctly about why this is happening. The easiest way I can think of to do what you're after is to use the not-often-used second argument to the callback function passed to the `filter` method, which takes an element's index:

```
arr = arr.filter((elt, index) => removeIndex.indexOf(index) == -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

Pass *index* as the second parameter to check whether that *index* includes or not in `removeIndex`. Return the element only if the current *index* does not exist in `removeIndex` array:

```js
var removeIndex = [2,3];
var arr = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1];
arr = arr.filter((i,idx) => !removeIndex.includes(idx));
console.log(arr); //[ 1,1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you mutate the array so the next time you loop through the array it's items will be changed and you won't have the same items at the same indexes. There is a fairly simple solution for your particular example :

```js
var removeIndex = [2,3].sort(); // This won't work with [3,2] for example
var arr = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1];

for (let i = 0; i < removeIndex.length; i++){
  arr.splice(removeIndex[i] - i, 1);
}

console.log(arr)
```

But I'd suggest using an immutable solution with `.filter` for example, like suggested in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filter` and come up with this clean code:

```
var removeIndex = [2,3];
var arr = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1];
var newArr = arr.filter(el => el !== 0);
console.log(newArr);
// [1,1,1,1,1]
```